# How to work on existing branch/repository in GitLab created by other user?

Tags: gitlab

I am new to GitLab. As i have given access to an existing repository by other user and i am supposed to work on that branch.
I am really not sure that how can i start working on the Project locally and then to commit the changes.

P.S.: I have to work using .Net

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clone the repository into your local machine.

```
git clone git://gitlab.com/myproject
```

now you can see your local branches

```
git branch
```

to see all the branches

```
git branch -a
```

Now if you want to work on a branch other than master,you need to create a local  branch tracking the remote one.

```
git checkout -b other_branch origin/other_branch
```

Now, you can start working on the other branch locally. Hope this helps.